# JS RegExp - Exact match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regExp and need to check a password field that accepts 8 to 20 letters.

I have **tried str.test or str.match** but they return true even when letters can exceed 20.

Is there a native method that can return true/false based on **exact match**.

RegExp

```
/.{8,20}/
```

Comment: use this  var exp = "/^{8,20}$/";

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use the following:

```
/^.{8,20}$/.test(yourString)
```

or

```
yourString.length >= 8 && yourString.length <= 20
```